# Define WCF Endpointbehaviors in Silverlight project to put message on a service bus for appFabric

Tags: silverlight, wcf, appfabric, servicebus, endpointbehavior

I am attempting to send statuses to appFabric via a service bus from a silverlight application. Everything is tested and working except for the Silverlight application itself which does not appear to have a way to define endpointBehaviors. Endpointbehaviors are needed to provide a sharedSecret when communicating on a servicebus. Does anyone know how to define the issuer secret in silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is not possible](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/186249.aspx). So I am going to have to use another service to forward requests.